# Why in this case the positional index is necessary?

Tags: python

I found this example on GeeksforGeeks:

```
tab = {'geeks': 4127, 'for': 4098, 'geek': 8637678} 

# using format() in dictionary 
print('Geeks: {0[geeks]:d}; For: {0[for]:d}; '
    'Geeks: {0[geek]:d}'.format(tab))
```

I tried taking out the positional index '0' and ran it like this and got the error:

```
>>> print('Geeks: {[geeks]:d}; For: {[for]:d}; Geeks: {[geek]:d}'.format(tab))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print('Geeks: {[geeks]:d}; For: {[for]:d}; Geeks: {[geek]:d}'.format(tab))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I don't quite understand what this error message means. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `print('Geeks: {geeks:d}; For: {for:d}; Geeks: {geek:d}'.format(**tab))` instead.

Comment: @Michael Butscher Your method makes sense to me. But i want to understand why the missing of positional index in my example would lead to the "tuple index out of range" error. I thought positional index is optional.

Comment: @sciroccorics I get the error in 3.6.3. I guess they changed it.

Comment: Since `format()` takes multiple arguments, you have to specify which argument you're formatting.

Comment: I'm not sure why an unspecified argument gets an "out of range" error, it's probably just an artifact of the way it processes the arguments internally.

Comment: I wrote too fast: the error happens also in 3.8. But after all, the error is normal: without numerical prefix, each {} pair seeks for another argument in the calling line of `format`. And it finds only one, instead of 3. Using the **tab form, as proposed by Michael, solves the pb elegantly.

Comment: With Python 3.8, the error message is more explicit : "IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple"

Comment: @sciroccorics Thank you for your answer. And yeah the 3.8 version error message is much clearer.